# SDH STM-n measured in multiples of E4

Tags: wan

I am studying an online course that has just covered the basic standards for WAN data transmission.

It covered the European Frame formats over Copper wires: E1 set as 32 x DS0 channel.

It then describes the SDH STM-1 Framing unit as being able to carry 1 x E4 unit.

What are the specifications for the E4 framing unit?
(in particular what is its maximum data rate and when is it used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According this wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-carrier#E4:_multiplexing_level_4:_140.C2.A0Mbit.2Fs

States that E4 has a Data rate of 139.26 Mbps and 2048 channels.

In terms of use it just seems to be another PDH multiplexed framing unit of data, capable of being used in a larger trunk fibre framing such as STM-n.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.